# Server does not receive HTTP headers that are sent by the browser?

Tags: http, web, http-headers, google-chrome-devtools

Now this is extremely weird. Somehow my api backend does not receive the http headers (specifically the authorization header), that are clearly sent by the web application, as one can see in the dev tools. But when I try to send a request from GraphiQL or Postman with a authorization header the server DOES get them. How is this possible?

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]
Log of received http headers in my backend:

```
map[Accept:[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9] Accept-Encoding:[gzip, deflate, br] Accept-Language:[de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7] Cache-Control:[no-cache] Connection:[keep-alive] Pragma:[no-cache] Sec-Fetch-Dest:[document] Sec-Fetch-Mode:[navigate] Sec-Fetch-Site:[none] Sec-Fetch-User:[?1] Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:[1] User-Agent:[Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the problem... It was sending the OPTIONS request first, which is sent without this header. My api denied the request because of the missing auth header and so the final POST request never happened.

Comment: Looking like preflight does not need Authorization header. But the POST needs it. Must be some other issue. Possibly the browser preflight expects some headers in the response from your server but does not see them?